# How to visible Plugin A all classes to Plugin B

Tags: treeview, eclipse-rcp, rcp

There are two Plugin. In First Plugin, there is a treeViewer and In Second Plugin, there is a registration form. so, treviewer is dependent on registration Form. when I pass value from registration form to treeviewer then TreeViewer class is not visible in Registration form.so, how to pass Value from registration form to Treeviewer.

Comment: We need a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question. You've given us nothing to work with

Answer (score 0):

You just need to [add a plugin dependency](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.pde.doc.user%2Fguide%2Ftools%2Feditors%2Fmanifest_editor%2Fdependencies.htm) in the manifest editor.

Comment: I add plugin dependency of 2nd plugin into 1st plugin. and i can see all classes of 2nd plugin into 1st plugin. But I cannot see all classes of 1st plugin into second plugin.